# How do I migrate from Developer Edition to Contact Manager Edition?

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, migration, data-migration

I'm ready to migrate a client from a Developer Edition environment to a Contact Manager environment.  In the past, I've always worked with an edition with API access and used Eclipse to do the migration, but I understand that is not possible with Contact Manager.

Is the recommended procedure to use the Migration Tool for metadata migration and then use the built-in Import Wizard to bring over any data they want migrated?  Or is there some other clever way to get this done?

Comment: I created an unmanaged package, which carried over a fair amount of my app.  I then exported and imported the data between accounts.  The biggest issue was all of the unsupported features in Contact Manager edition (i.e. no API access, no APEX code, can't rename fields).  Thx everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Contact Manager edition doesn't support Metadata API migrating with Eclipse or Migration Tool is indeed not possible.

Because the migration is from Org to Org, Change Sets are also not possible.

Can you create an unmanaged package and install that? Downside is that packages are very limited.

Comment: So the Migration Tool requires API access, as well?  I don't know if the unmanaged package would work as I've never had to use it.  What are the limitations you mentioned?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging has a list with the supported metadata types.